# How do I get the current Security.Claims.AuthorizationContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

I am doing Claim based security trimming for my menu, and I need access to `AuthorizationContext`.

I can get the `RequestContext` or `HttpContext` but I do not know how to get `AuthorizationContext`.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to access to AuthorizationContext?

Comment: @cuongle I need it to write tests.